# Trying to get data from a API

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, python-requests

I want to get a list that contains the exchange rate for USD.

This displays the data inside the API for reference.

```
def ge(url):
  response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  content_str = response.read()
  content = json.loads(content_str)
  return json.dumps(content)

print (ge(url))
```

And I'm having trouble with this part of the code where I can't get the exchange rate for USD. My other problem is that when I get rid of `'base in i'`, I get a error message saying the following, "string indices must be integers".

```
import json
import urllib.request

url = "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest"

def get_response(url):
  response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  content_str = response.read()
  content = json.loads(content_str)
  outList = []
  for i in content:
    if('rates' in i and 'base' in i):
      innerList = []
      innerList.append(float(i["USD"]))
      outList.append(innerList)
  return json.dumps(outList)

print (get_response(url))
```

Expected: 1.1218

Actual result: I keep getting a empty bracket with nothing in it.

Comment: It's impossible to know what is `content` without reading API doc because it depends on returned JSON, if you'd like to make the post helpful, post your sample data.

Comment: Given that error message, at least one element in `content` must be a plain string, and you can't index a string with `i["USD"]`.

Comment: Click here ```"https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest"``` for content.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example. The problem lies within the handling of the data, not urllib.

Comment: content is a dictionary, so ```i``` will be the key of dictionary. In this case, string. do string[string] cause the error

Comment: so ```str["USD"] ``` ?

Comment: `content['base']['USD']` is what you want. You should brush up on the basics as you seem to have no idea what a string or a dictionary is.

Comment: use `print(content, type(content) )` to see what you have. If it is list then you can check `print( content[0], type(content[0]) )`. If it is dictionary then you can check `print( content.keys() )`, etc.

Comment: @ShioT actually, it's `content['rates']['USD']`. The value for the key `base` is 'EUR'.

Comment: @101arrowz That was an honest typo and the comment is too old to be edited. Oh well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `urllib` GET request is merely returning a dictionary. We see it contains three keys: `base` (whose value is 'EUR'), `rates` (whose value is a dictionary containing conversion rates to the other currencies), and `date` (whose value is the current date). You want to get the conversion rate of USD. We therefore access the `rates` key with `content['rates']`. This returns a dictionary with keys being currency names ('GBP', 'USD', etc.) whose values are the amount of that currency that is required to equal 1 of the base. To access the value of the `USD` entry, we do `content['rates']['USD']`, which returns the desired result of `1.1218` USD per euro. These are basic python concepts, so be sure to know them before moving on to more advanced projects.

Revised code:

```
def get_response(url):
  response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  content_str = response.read()
  content = json.loads(content_str)
  return content['rates']['USD']
```

Answer (score 1):

Tips:You can add`print(content)` after the line `content=json.loads(content_str)`,and then you could see the type of `content`, it's a nested `Dictionary`.
     @101arrowZ's code works well. We don't need to check whether the keys `rates` and `base` are in the dictionary, for the 'check' part is contained in `content['rates']['USD']`. If they are in `content`, the value may be returned; otherwise, return none.

Comment: Ahh.. I see what you mean, I will try that. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm very glad to help. Your question was my first answer on stackoverflow. What I told you above was the process of how I got the answer of your question. I ran the code on my computer and it worked.